# dice_values within a function aren't returning, could someone please explain my error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to simulate a dice roll game.
My problem is that when I roll the dice whithin my function and then later call it, 
when I display try to display the die1, die2, die3 value from another function the values ar empty, unless I use global values, but I want to understand how the functions work and what i'm doing wrong rather than work around with global. :)

```
#importing the random library to make the random.randint function available
import random


#Making declrations for variable values
total_games = (0)
chip_balance = 100
total_chips = ()
games_won = 0
games_lost = 0
even_stevens = 0
games_draw = 0
play_game = 0
die1 = ()
die2 = ()
die3 = ()

#defining the dice roll function and logic
def die_roll(die1, die2, die3):
    #Global Statements to make the die values available to the pre_display_dice function and the display_dice function.

    die1 = random.randint (1, 12)
    die2 = random.randint (1, 12)
    die3 = random.randint (1, 12)
    return die1, die2, die3




#defining the authorship details in this function
def display_details():
    print('File       : tobxz001_inbetween.py')


#defining the get_play_game_function to set the loop
def get_play_game():
    global play_game
    play_game = input('Would you like to play in-between  [y|n]?')
    while play_game != 'y' and play_game != 'n':
        play_game = input("please enter either 'y' or 'n': ")
        play_game = play_game.lower()
    return play_game

#defining  the Play_again function
def play_again():
    global play_game
    play_game = input('Would you like to play again squire?')
    while play_game != 'y' and play_game != 'n':
        play_game = input("please enter either 'y' or 'n' :")
        play_game = play_game.lower()


#Defining the dice display here. Only two values are displayed before the bet is made
def pre_display_dice():
    print('Dice rolled:')
    print('+-------------------------------------+')
    print('|    Die 1    |        |    Die 2     |')
    print('|     ',die1,'     |    0   |    ',die2, '       |')
    print('+-------------------------------------+')


#Defining the final dice roll display with all values of the roll displayed after the bet is made
def display_dice():
    print('Dice rolled:')
    print('+-------------------------------------+')
    print('|    Die 1    |        |    Die 2     |')
    print('|     ',die1,'     |  ',die3, '   |    ',die2, '       |')
    print('+-------------------------------------+')


#Defining the game summary here. Wins, Loses, and draws are called from this function at the end of the game
def game_summary():
    print('\n')
    print('Game Summary')
    print('============')
    print('\n')
    print('You played',total_games,'Games:')
    print('|--> Games Won:', games_won)
    print('|--> Games Lost', games_lost)
    print('|--> Even-Stevens:', even_stevens)

display_details()


get_play_game()

while play_game == 'y':

     die_roll(die1, die2, die3)

     temp = int()
     winner = ()
     loser = (0)
     bet_result = ()

     #Code for swapping the dice around to always display the lower value on the left
     if (die1 >= die2):
         temp = die1
         die1 = die2
         die2 = temp
     else:
         die1 = die1
         die2 = die2

     if die1 == die2:
         total_games = total_games + 1
         print('\n')
         print('You hit the post')
         print("Even-Stevens! Let\'s play again!")
         print('\n')


     get_play_game


     pre_display_dice()
     print('\n')
     print("Number of Chips : ", chip_balance)


     bet = input("Place your bet: ")
     while bet == '':
          bet = input("Can't be an empty bet please try again ")
     while bet.isalpha():
          bet = input("Must be a numerical value entered \n \n Place You're bet:")
     bet = int(bet)


     while bet > chip_balance:
          print('Sorry, you may only bet what you have ')
          bet = input("Place your bet: ")
          while bet == '':
              bet = input("Can't be an empty bet please try again ")
          while bet.isalpha() or bet == '':
              bet = input("Must be a numerical value entered \n \n Place You're bet:")

     bet = int(bet)

     chip_balance = chip_balance - bet

     if die1 < die3 & die3 < die2:
         winner = (bet * 2) + chip_balance
         chip_balance = winner
     else:
         chip_balance

#Code to compare if the results are even or not STAGE 3, if they aren't Die3 will be rolled
     if die1 == die2:
         print('\n')
         display_dice()
         print('You hit the post')
         print("Even-Stevens! Let\'s play again!")
         print('\n')
         even_stevens = even_stevens + 1
         total_games = total_games + 1
     else:
          print('\n')
          display_dice()
          print('\n')

     #Winning and Losing logic
     #Winning conditions
     if die1 < die3 & die3 < die2:
         print("***You Win!***")
         print("You now have", chip_balance, "Chips")
         print('\n')
         games_won = games_won + 1
         total_games = total_games + 1
     #Evaluate to see if any of the dice' match is done here
     elif die1 == die3 or die3 == die2:
         print('\n')
         print("***You hit the post - You Lose! ***")
         print("You now have", chip_balance, "chips left")
         print('\n')
         games_lost = games_lost + 1
         total_games = total_games + 1
     #Losing Logic           
     else:
         print("*** Sorry - You Lose! ***")
         print('\n')
         print("You now have", chip_balance, "chips left!")
         games_lost = games_lost + 1
         total_games = total_games + 1

     #Chip balance check, if it's zero, game is over, otherwise keep playing
     if chip_balance == 0:
           print('\n')
           print('You\'re all out of chips! \n ***GAME OVER***')
           play_game = 'n'
     else:
         play_again()


     if play_game == 'n':
         game_summary()

if play_game == 'n':
    print('\n')
    print('No worries... another time perhaps...:)')
```

Comment: it seems like the problem is you need to save the returned result of the `die_roll()` function into variables, try `die1, die2, die3 = die_roll(die1, die2, die3)`

Comment: Thankyou, that did it, I put it into the main loop and it's good. I'm struggling to understand functions, but i'm sure with perseverance I'll get there..